# No attribute 'sort' over iterable object in Python?

Tags: python, sorting, attributes, iteration

I am running a module reading folders through a loop using os.scandir, and I need to sort my files through the loop and within the output. Right now the output randomly organises the files. So, I set a helper at the beginning to direct the sorting:

```
def dir_name(dir):
    return dir.name
with os.scandir(basedirectory) as folders:
    print(folders)
```

The output was: <posix.ScandirIterator object at 0x7fb070492490>

This is good, right? I want to iterate over the folders in this directory.
So then I write:

```
 with os.scandir(basedirectory) as folders:
    folders=[folder for folder in folders if folder.is_dir()]
    folders=folders.sort(key=dir_name)
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [58], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 folders=folders.sort(key=dir_name)

AttributeError: 'posix.ScandirIterator' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

I tried `folders=folders.sort_value(key=dir_name)` with the same error. I can't see how to further define sort. Is the issue the iterator? How would I go about solving this? Note that I'm new to writing code in python (have used pre-written modules only before).

Comment: `list.sort()` doesn't return the sorted list, it sorts the list in place. So you shouldn't assign the result back to `folders`.

Comment: Can't reproduce. This looks like it has been run without the line before.

Comment: I don't see how you would get that error, since you redefined `folders` to be a `list` on the previous line.

Comment: What should I assign the result to? For Klaus D.: there is a previous line stating what the basedirectory is (just a folder on my machine).  For chepner: exactly, this is why I'm confused!

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to solve this problem:

```
 with os.scandir(basedirectory) as folders:
    f = [folder for folder in folders if folder.is_dir()]
    f.sort(key=dir_name)
```

or

```
with os.scandir(basedirectory) as folders:
    f = [folder for folder in folders if folder.is_dir()]
    f = sorted(folders, key=dir_name)
```

Comment: Don't I run the risk of it saying AttributeError: 'posix.ScandirIterator' object has no attribute 'sorted'? That is what happened when I had folders.sort_value

Comment: Also thanks! I will try these.

Comment: Your issue is you were assigning `folders` to a method while using the same variable as your `with` alias.

Comment: I implemented this and it worked very well. Thank you for the help!